# How to calculate average word & Sentence length in python 2.7 from a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been stuck on this for the past 2 weeks was wondering could you help.

I am trying to calculate the average word length & sentence length from a text file. I just cant seem to wrap my head around it. I have just started using functions which are then called in the main file.

My Main file looks like so

```
import Consonants
import Vowels
import Sentences
import Questions
import Words

""" Vowels """


text = Vowels.fileToString("test.txt")    
x = Vowels.countVowels(text)

print str(x) + " Vowels"

""" Consonats """

text = Consonants.fileToString("test.txt")    
x = Consonants.countConsonants(text)


print str(x) + " Consonants"

""" Sentences """


text = Sentences.fileToString("test.txt")    
x = Sentences.countSentences(text)
print str(x) + " Sentences"


""" Questions """

text = Questions.fileToString("test.txt")    
x = Questions.countQuestions(text)

print str(x) + " Questions"

""" Words """
text = Words.fileToString("test.txt")    
x = Words.countWords(text)

print str(x) + " Words"
```

And one of my function files are like so:

```
def fileToString(filename):
    myFile = open(filename, "r")
    myText = ""
    for ch in myFile:
        myText = myText + ch
    return myText

def countWords(text):
    vcount = 0
    spaces = [' ']
    for letter in text:
        if (letter in spaces):
            vcount = vcount + 1
    return vcount
```

I was wondering how I would go about calculating the word length as a function that I import? I tried using some of the other threads here but they did not work for me correctly.

Comment: what constitutes a sentence? does it end in `.` or `?` or `!`....?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes i have all three of does for the Sentences function.

Comment: for words you could split each line and sum the lengths of the returned lists, if you have the lines extracted just do the same. You will be including punctuation though so you will need to catch those cases if you really want an accurate count

Comment: We don't know what `Consonants`, `Vowels`, `Sentences`, and etc are, so it's hard to help you. Note however that `fileToString` is equivalent to `with open(filename) as myFile: return myFile.read()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to give you an algorithm for that,

- Read the file, make a `for` loop using `enumerate()`, `split()` it and check how they ends with `endswith()`. Like;

`for ind,word in enumerate(readlines.split()):
    if word.endswith("?")
    .....
    if word.endswith("!")`

Then put them in a dict, use the `ind`(index) value with a `while` loop;

```
obj = "Hey there! how are you? I hope you are ok."
dict1 = {}
for ind,word in enumerate(obj.split()):
    dict1[ind]=word

x = 0
while x<len(dict1):
    if "?" in dict1[x]:
        print (list(dict1.values())[:x+1])
    x += 1
```

Output;

```
>>> 
['Hey', 'there!', 'how', 'are', 'you?']
>>>
```

You see, I actually cut the words until reach `?`. So I have a sentence in a list now(you can change it to `!`). I can reach every element's length, the rest of it is simple mathematic. You will find the sum of every element's length then divide it to lenght of that list. Theorically, It will give the average.

Remember that, it's the algorithm. You *really* have to change this codes to fit with your data, the key points are `enumerate()`, `endswith()` and `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly when you're matching things like words and sentences, you're better off learning and using regular expressions than just relying on `str.split` to catch every corner case.

```
#text.txt
Here is some text. It is written on more than one line, and will have several sentences.

Some sentences will have their OWN line!

It will also have a question. Is this the question? I think it is.
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

with open('test.txt') as infile:
    data = infile.read()

sentence_pat = re.compile(r"""
    \b                # sentences will start with a word boundary
    ([^.!?]+[.!?]+)   # continue with one or more non-sentence-ending
                      #    characters, followed by one or more sentence-
                      #    ending characters.""", re.X)

word_pat = re.compile(r"""
    (\S+)             # Words are just groups of non-whitespace together
    """, re.X)

sentences = sentence_pat.findall(data)
words = word_pat.findall(data)

average_sentence_length = sum([len(sentence) for sentence in sentences])/len(sentences)
average_word_length = sum([len(word) for word in words])/len(words)
```

DEMO:

```
>>> sentences
['Here is some text.',
 'It is written on more than one line, and will have several sentences.',
 'Some sentences will have their OWN line!',
 'It will also have a question.',
 'Is this the question?',
 'I think it is.']

>>> words
['Here',
 'is',
 'some',
 'text.',
 'It',
 'is',
 ... ,
 'I',
 'think',
 'it',
 'is.']

>>> average_sentence_length
31.833333333333332

>>> average_word_length
4.184210526315789
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this:

> I was wondering how I would go about calculating the word length as a
>   function that I import?

```
def avg_word_len(filename):
    word_lengths = []
    for line in open(filename).readlines():
        word_lengths.extend([len(word) for word in line.split()])
    return sum(word_lengths)/len(word_lengths)
```

Note: This doesn't consider things like . and ! at end of word.. etc..

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't apply if you want to make the script yourself, but I would use NLTK. It has some really great tools for dealing with really long texts.

[This page](https://blogs.princeton.edu/etc/files/2014/03/Text-Analysis-with-NLTK-Cheatsheet.pdf) provides a cheat-sheet for nltk. You should be able to import your text, get the sentances as a large list of lists and get the list of n-grams (words of length n). Then you can calculate the average.